# R base plot system: substitute default axis with user-define axis without overlapping

Tags: r, plot, overlap

I have the following code to generate a line graph with base plot system and reset x axis values with a vector of three week days (Tuesday, Friday and Saturday):

```
plot(data$obsn, data$Global_active_power, type = "l")
axis(1, at = c(0, mean(data$obsn), max(data$obsn)),
     labels = c("Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

I was expecting the second line to substitute the x axis default values, but instead of that, the new x axis values overlap the previous values and I get a mess.

How can I do to substitute the x default axis values with my new ones instead of overlapping them?

Comment: @李哲源 Thanks, so the annotation is never aimed to substitute previous lables? Is strictly neccesary to specify the `xaxt` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = data.frame(obsn=0:2, Global_active_power=runif(3))  # Sample data

plot(data$obsn, data$Global_active_power, type = "l", axes=FALSE)  # No axis

axis(1, at = c(0, mean(data$obsn), max(data$obsn)),  # Adds x axis
     labels = c("Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
axis(2)  # Adds y axis
```

See `?axis` for more details. [This](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html) guide might also help.